# Add a timeout within a foreach loop and write to host - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that runs through all share paths within a csv file and invokes a quick `Get-ChildItem` to count the number of files within the folder/subfolders etc.  This is working but it is taking an age, especially if a folder have more than 500k files.

I would like to add a timeout within the loop, so that it will just write-host and then output into another column 'TIMED OUT' but i can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried a few different ways but somehow my loop breaks and runs the top line in my csv over and over.

This is the code i have so far:

```
...

#Import middle to filter unique
$sharesMiddle = Import-Csv -Path './middle.csv' | Sort-Object NFTSPath -Unique
$result = foreach ($share in $sharesMiddle) {
    #Replace the colon for $ within the path
    $nftsPath = join-path \\ $share.AssetName $share.Path.Replace(':', '$')
    $path = $share.Path 
    $count = Invoke-Command -computername $share.AssetName -ScriptBlock { param($path) (Get-ChildItem $path -File -Recurse).count } -Credential $Cred -Verbose -ArgumentList $path 

    Write-Host $nftsPath : $count
    
    $share | Select-Object *, @{n = "Files"; e = { $count } }
        
}

$result | Export-CSV '.\newcsvfile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help on this would be super!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following which should be suitable for you:

```
# define the time limit in seconds
$TimeoutLimitSeconds = 2

# Define the job, start job
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {420+69 ; start-sleep -Seconds 3}

# Await job
$job | Wait-Job -Timeout ( $TimeoutLimitSeconds ) | Out-Null

# If job doesn't finish before the time limit is reached
if ($job.state -eq 'Running') {

    # Job timed out
    $job | Stop-Job | Remove-Job
    $job = $null
    $output = "TIMED OUT"

# If job managed to finalize in time
}Else{

     # Finished on time
     $job | Stop-Job 
     $output = Receive-Job $job
     $job | Remove-Job

}

# Write the output to host
Write-Host "output is: $output"
```

output is: TIMED OUT

```
# define the time limit in seconds
$TimeoutLimitSeconds = 4

# Define the job, start job
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {420+69 ; start-sleep -Seconds 3}

# Await job
$job | Wait-Job -Timeout ( $TimeoutLimitSeconds ) | Out-Null

# If job doesn't finish before the time limit is reached
if ($job.state -eq 'Running') {

    # Job timed out
    $job | Stop-Job | Remove-Job
    $job = $null
    $output = "TIMED OUT"

# If job managed to finalize in time
}Else{

     # Finished on time
     $job | Stop-Job 
     $output = Receive-Job $job
     $job | Remove-Job

}

# Write the output to host
Write-Host "output is: $output"
```

output is: 489

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel, based on this - do i just need to add my whole foreach block within the `Start-Job -ScriptBlock` block?